# How to convert AutocadDWG To PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, autocad, dwg

Is there another way to convert AutocadDWG To PDF but to use third party programs?   Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to do it without AutoCAD then [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendesign.com/) is one of the few options that I have found.   If you have AutoCAD installed there is a PDF driver in the newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use DWG Trueview ([free from AutoDesk](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=6703438&siteID=123112)) and print through a PDF print driver. [PDF Xchange](http://www.docu-track.com/) is the best PDF printer I have found for AutoCAD. Most others, including AutoCAD's own implementation bloat the PDF to about 10x the size and render text as line objects. That's a total FAIL.

You used to be able to hook into bits of Trueview programmatically but it never had a documented API as such and certaily wasn't officially sanctioned. Try Google for solutions along those lines.

Comment: The PDF driver in AutoCAD 2010 is much-improved over previous version and is quite usable. It is now my default for DWG - PDF.